# Cloudfront and multiple Lambda@Edge functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Cloudfront distribution pointing at a custom url.
In that distribution, I have setup 2 lambda function associations.
1 on the Cloudfront event of viewer-request to query parameter store and redirect to the correct url
The other on the Cloudfront event of origin-response to gather response stats from the call.

The viewer-reqest function is as follows - **note** dummy urls for purpose of question

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const origin = "main";
    const primaryUrl = "https://www.google.com";
    const drUrl = "https://www.yahoo.com";

    let url = primaryUrl;

    if (origin != "main") {
        url = drUrl;
    } else {
        url = primaryUrl;
    }

    const response = {
        status: '302',
        statusDescription: 'Found',
        headers: {
            location: [{
                key: 'Location',
                value: url,
            }],
        },
    };

    return response;
};
```

The origin response lambda is very simple for now
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' });
var cloudwatch = new AWS.CloudWatch();

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    console.log("Custom Metrics Event");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event));

    const response = {
        status: '200', 
    };

    return response;
};
```

When I call the cloudfront distribution domain, the viewer-request lambda@edge kicks in but the origin-response lambda does not trigger and I see nothing in cloudwatch
If I remove the viewer-request lambda - the origin-response lambda does trigger

Am I doing anything wrong here or does anyone have any recommendations?

Thank you
Damien

Comment: If you remove the redirect part of the `viewer-request` Lambda does it work?

Comment: let me try that now

Comment: @chriswilliams no joy when I try that

Comment: @ChrisWilliams do you know of any samples for valid nodejs functions for each of the cloudfront events like viewer-request and viewer-response?

Comment: The best examples I have are https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-generating-http-responses.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html. Request events return request, response events return response.

Comment: thanks @ChrisWilliams very useful indeed. So with that do you know is it possible to redirect to a completely different path in a viewer-request lambda and still hit the other lambda@Edge functions (e.g. origin-response lambda)

Comment: I'm not 100% on that one, I generally see the redirects normally occur on the origin response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ChrisWilliams comment was accurate
I changed my code to perform the redirect in the origin response and all worked fine then